# Architecture azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function with an azure storage queue trigger. It runs fine without any problems. Inside the queue there will be saved a json and then the function does their job.
But now we need more functionality. I like to expand the json with a functionality key. Now is it better to expand also the function
If functionality = A go to class A 
Else go to class B

Or is it better to create a new function with the same trigger?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is okay to have different classes in the function.

To make the function responsible only for a particular process, you can split it into two functions and have [Service Bus Topic Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions) instead of Storage Queues. This will keep the implementation reliable as Service Bus got wide set of features when compared to Storage Queues.

You can use Rules in Topic Subscriptions for filtering the messages.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are just like traditional apps. There's no issues in referencing a class library that handles that deserializing.

What you are looking for is a concept called Message Versioning. It's a heavy topic so I may not be able to handle it here completely but versioning will happen.

One possibility, is to consider each messages as a Command (read on CQRS). You could pre parse the version number in the message and have a CommandHandler for each version.

This is not specific to Functions. Here's a piece of advice Functions related. Keep a single function. With versioning happening, it will be simpler to debug and find what Functions is still working or not.